# web-dev - Real-time page update from database based on special ID

Tags: asp.net, spring, web-services, session, real-time

I'm trying to build a web app that lets a user create a session which generates a unique session ID through which other users can join the session and post messages on a board. However, I am stuck at real-time updates for the specific sessions as I am unaware of technologies that allow me to accomplish this task. I've read about .NET's SignalR as a real-time web app API but so far have not found a way to handle each session separately. I am looking for recommendations and preferably tutorials on how to implement this feature.

The Web API is built in Spring Boot and .NET, so I would prefer APIs/tutorials for these frameworks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking of the easiest way to do this with minimal strain on the server. I think I would go down the road of storing the session IDs in the db and then use ajax to handle the realtime updates. Ajax can run on a js timing loop that can check a serverside flag which is set once updates are made to the db. Upon finding a set flag the ajax can then pull in the updates or do a page refresh.